# jqGrid saveCell method returns nothing except gridelement. can i get true/false or can i pass a callback to saveCell?

Tags: jqgrid

I am using jqgrid 3.8. I have a grid which is having some editable columns.I also have an update button to save the grid contents on the server.

If user clicks on editable cell and changes the content and then clicks on update button, i am doing the following things.(after clicking on cell user directly clicks on update button)

first i am calling jqGrid 'savecell' method with iRow, iCol.
here the cell is being saved/ showing popup for validations.

but i want a callback to know whether cell is saved/not so that i can stop or continue my save functionality.

my sample code is like this

```
function updateGrid(){
        // i have iRow, iCol references in beforeEditCell event as grideditRow, grideditCol.. these values r not getting modified nowhere else..
    $(gridid).jqGrid('saveCell', grideditRow, grideditCol);

    //logic to get grid data using getchangedcells and send ajax call to server.
    var changedCells = $(gridid).jqGrid('getChangedCells', 'dirty');
}
```

how can i stop update logic after saveCell call if savecell is failed. saveCell is returning only jqgrid element.

is there any mechanism to get true/false from savecell or can i pass some callback to savecell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are [afterSaveCell](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acell_editing#events) and [errorCell](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acell_editing#events) events. One of the events will be called after saving the cell on the server. If you implement the corresponding event handler, you will be notified whether the saving of the new cell value was successful or not.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response oleg.. i am using clientArray. can u tell me how i can use the afterSaveCell in place of saveCell in the above scenario. already i am using afterSaveCell for updating other cell contents of the samegrid based on the current edit.

Comment: @usergigantic: If you use `cellsubmit: 'clientArray'` parameter you can just use `afterSaveCell` bacause the `errorCell` event will not used. You can add to the list of parameters of jqGrid the additional parameter `afterSaveCell: function (rowid, cellname, value, iRow, iCol) {/*your code here*/}`. Inside your `afterSaveCell` implementation you place the code which are used currently after the  `saveCell`. Which kind of errors you have if you don't save that data on the server?

Comment: Thanks oleg.. i got the idea.. as you said, i moved that code to the afterSaveCell function.                                                       i am getting error popups which are defined by me in jqgridmin.js checkValues() function.. that is fine for me.. thanks again...

Comment: @usergigantic: You are welcome! I wish you a lot of fun and pleasure on the stackoverflow.